# Ignoring the devise routes does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I am trying to write an API for app's sign-in/sign-up custom procedures but want to use the devise's features through my app. The problem is without defining the `devise_for :users` or `devise_scope :user` in `config/routes.rb` the devise's map does not get created and so I cannot use `sign_in @user` and etc.

## Question:

How can I use the devise's features without its routes enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # root controller#action
  root 'home#index'
  # define the devise's user and
  #   disable direct access to devise's routes
  devise_for :users, skip: :all
end
```